# SQL Server: INNER JOIN after UNION leads to slow Hash Match (Aggregate)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, union

Here is a CTE that slows down the whole stored procedure:

```
select * 
from #finalResults
where intervalEnd is not null
union
select            
    two.startTime, 
    two.endTime,
    two.intervalEnd,
    one.barcodeID,
    one.id,
    one.pairId,
    one.bookingTypeID,
    one.cardID,
    one.factor,
    two.openIntervals,
    two.factorSumConcurrentJobs
from #finalResults as one
inner join #finalResults as two
    on  two.cardID = one.cardID
    and two.startTime > one.startTime
    and two.startTime < one.intervalEnd
```

The table #finalResults contains a little over 600K lines, the upper part of the UNION (`where intervalEnd is not null`) about 580K rows, the lower part with the joined #finalResults roughly 300K rows. However, this inner join estimates to end up with a whooping 100 mio. rows, which might be responsible for the long-running Hash Match here:
[image]

Now if I [understand Hash Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189313.aspx) correctly, the smaller table should be hashed first and the larger table inserted, and if you guess the sizes wrong at first, you get performance penalties due to mid-process role reversal. Might this be responsible for the slowness?
I tried an explicit `inner merge join` and `inner loop join` in hopes of improving the row count estimate, but to no avail.
One other thing: the Eager Spool on the bottom right estimates 17K rows, ends up with 300K rows and performs almost half a million rebinds and rewrites. Is this normal?

**Edit:**
The temp table #finalResults has an index on it:

```
create nonclustered index "finalResultsIDX_cardID_intervalEnd_startTime__REST"
on #finalresults( "cardID", "intervalEnd", "startTime" )
include( barcodeID, id, pairID, bookingTypeID, factor,
         openIntervals, factorSumConcurrentJobs );
```

Do I need to build a separate statistic on it as well?

Comment: It's not a Hash join, it's a Hash match. It's the duplicate removal for the UNION operator (note, it only has a single input)

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced situations where `UNION`'s made a query much slower than `UNION ALL` with a `DISTINCT` afterwards. So while I don't have an explanation for the bad query plan (statistics and indexes are okay?), I suggest that you try the following:

```
select distinct * from (
    select * 
    from #finalResults
    where intervalEnd is not null
    union all
    select            
        two.startTime, 
        two.endTime,
        two.intervalEnd,
        one.barcodeID,
        one.id,
        one.pairId,
        one.bookingTypeID,
        one.cardID,
        one.factor,
        two.openIntervals,
        two.factorSumConcurrentJobs
    from #finalResults as one
    inner join #finalResults as two
        on  two.cardID = one.cardID
        and two.startTime > one.startTime
        and two.startTime < one.intervalEnd
)
```

Comment: I already did: it gives the same execution plan as selecting from the original CTE with a `option(order group)`, i.e. it takes the same time as before, it just spends it sorting instead of hashing.

Comment: Yep, looking at that query plan, the Hash Match has only a single input - so it's the removal of duplicates by UNION that's causing the issue (and no hints on the join will help)

Comment: I see. Maybe a `UNION ALL` where you make sure not to add duplicate records by using `ÈXCEPT` might help then, because it would avoid sorting the 580K rows from the first part?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will improve if you create statistics for the cardID column.